# How to assert all values in a Pandas dataframe's column have a desired length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert

I have Pandas dataframe, that has the length of "state" column. I am 100% sure, the length of all the values in the column is 2. When I try to write an assert statement, I am getting an assertion error. I am not sure if I am using the assert statement correctly. Please help.

```
assert df['state'].str.len().all() == 2
```

My understanding: assert that all the values in the state column have a length that is equal to 2. Please let me know if this is correct. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

You have the order a bit messed up.

In your code `df['state'].str.len().all()` checks if all the lengths are different from `0`, which returns a single `True/False` or `1/0`. And when you compare that to a single `2`, it's always `False` and trigger the `assert`.

It should be:

```
assert (df['state'].str.len() == 2).all()
```

Comment: assert df['state'].str.upper().all() == True. Is this correct to check if all the values are uppercase. I am getting an assertion error

Comment: Same story, `.all()` here tries to convert the strings in each cell to a boolean and checks for `False`, which corresponds to the empty strings. You want `df['state'].str.isupper().all()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please bear with me. I didnt quite understand what you are trying to say. what do you mean by" .all() here tries to convert the strings in each cell to a boolean and checks for False" .

Comment: What do you think `.all()` does?

Comment: From my understanding, all()  checks all the values and would throw assertion error even if one value doesn't the condition

Comment: `.all` has nothing to do with `assert`. `.all()` checks the series for any `False` values. So `pd.Series([True, False, True]).all()` is `False`, and `pd.Series([True, True, True]).all()` is `True`. Now, if you call `.all` on a string-valued series, e.g. `s=pd.Series(['ab', 'cd', ''])`, then `s.all()` is equivalent to `s.astype(bool).all()`.

Comment: ah ah ah, got it..Thank you so much. You are awesome. Keep rocking. :)